# Issue with Filestream Filetable not computing file_type column on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, filestream, filetable

I am having a problem with my filestream filetable, when I run an insert statement on it the file saves, but the file_type column is null (and obviously cannot be updated manually given that it's a computed column)

```
DECLARE @counter INT, @maxPolicySectionId INT
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @file_stream VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @fileTable TABLE(
name NVARCHAR(50),
filePath NVARCHAR(128),
polSecId INT
);

--...Populate @fileTable from database table...--

SELECT @counter = MIN(policySectionId), @maxPolicySectionId = MAX(policySectionId) FROM tblPolicySection

SET @name = (SELECT name FROM @fileTable WHERE polSecId = @counter)

SET @path = (SELECT filePath FROM @fileTable WHERE polSecId = @counter)
SET @path = REPLACE(@path, '192.168.0.6', 'meta-filesrv') 

--SET @file_type in Filetable somehow.. unable to perform UPDATE because it's a computed column

SET @command = N'SELECT @file_stream1 = CAST(bulkcolumn AS varbinary(MAX))
            from OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @path + ''',
            SINGLE_BLOB) AS x'  

EXEC sp_executesql @command, N'@file_stream1 VARBINARY(MAX) OUTPUT',@file_stream1 = @file_stream OUTPUT

IF @path IS NOT NULL AND @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BlobDocStore(
            name,
            file_stream
        )
        SELECT
            @name,
            @file_stream
 END

 SET @counter = @counter + 1
```

As you can see I am passing a stream into the insert statement which should work to the best of my understanding. I'm hoping someone has had some experience with this in the past. Thanks.

Comment: There is no `file_type` column in your `@fileTable` table.

Comment: That is just a temporary table to arrange my data before inserting to BlobDocStore which has the fixed schema of a filetable. The only two mandatory fields to insert data for is name and file_stream unless i'm mistaken, and the filetype should be generated based off of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file_type is derived from the specified file name. If the file_type column is `NULL`, this suggests the @name value does not have a file extension.